# Differentiating Original and "Publish in all child" transactions in Events System

Tags: web8.5, event-system, tom.net

Is there any way where I can differentiate Original transactions and the ones which are result of "Publish in all child publications" in Event System using TOM.NET?
I need this because I need to work on them differently, but from transaction object I have no info if it is the "parent" transaction, or result of resolver "Publish in all child publications" action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After long investigation, I have found that it is not possible to differentiate them. The resolving is done pre-transaction-create. Also, there in the transaction object, there is no property saying that it is a "child" transaction.